# cron job not starting on bootup

Tags: raspbian, python, cron

I've created a cron job and it does seem to be running.  This is the line I've put in cron file :

```
@reboot python /home/pi/Pimoroni/bme680/Indoor-Air-Quality-MQTT.py &
```

I ran the command `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` to get the list of cron tasks :

```
Dec  6 13:24:54 TBHPowerPaintPlant cron[327]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Dec  6 13:24:54 TBHPowerPaintPlant cron[327]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Dec  6 13:24:54 TBHPowerPaintPlant CRON[380]: (root) CMD (python /home/pi/Pimoroni/bme680/Indoor-Air-Quality-MQTT.py &)
```

The script itself contains a line to log to a file when it first runs and this log file is also empty. The script runs fine from the command prompt using `python /home/pi/Pimoroni/bme680/Indoor-Air-Quality-MQTT.py`  Can anyone tell me what I need to do to this script to run on boot up?

Thanks

Comment: The script probably has a different home directory (possibly /root),  You need to make sure that your script and any software it uses has the full path specified to any files/programs it uses.

Comment: So it should be python /root/home/pi/Pimoroni/bme680/Indoor-Air-Quality-MQTT.py?

Comment: No.  You need to google linux paths and understand the difference between absolute and relative paths.

Comment: From my understanding, home/pi is the user folder and is the full path? Should i move the script to another location to make sure.  Is there a recommended location for running scripts on system startup?

Comment: There is no need for the explicit `python` in the call, neither for the ampersand. So a `@reboot /home/pi/Pimoroni/bme680/Indoor-Air-Quality-MQTT.py` ought to be enough. Do make sure that this script is executable (`chmod 755 /home/pi/Pimoroni/bme680/Indoor-Air-Quality-MQTT.py`)

Comment: @steviethecat The explicit python is needed unless the script ends in py and the script contains a shebang and the script is executable and the shell accepts this convention.  Perhaps simplest to leave python as the prefix.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I've ran the chmod 755 command and still same response from the "grep CRON /var/log/syslog"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron not finding necessary files to run .py file](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74511/cron-not-finding-necessary-files-to-run-py-file)

Comment: The script is running, so what's the problem? Presumably it doesn't do what you want it to do, but you haven't told us what it's supposed to do or how it fails. The comment by @joan is almost surely the answer, by the way. EVERYTHING, including what's inside the script (and you haven't shown) needs an absolute path. The cron job will run with different environment variables than you have in your command line shell.